# R string encoding mess with RODBC in Rstudio

Tags: r, encoding, rodbc

I have a table with first and last names on a MYSQL data.base with UTF-8(?) encoding that do not render properly when loaded into R.
For info the database encoding looks like this

[image]

I try to query it in R from Rstudio with RODBC:

1st try:

```
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
conn <- odbcConnect("my_db", DBMSencoding = "")
sqlStr <- "SELECT id, first_name, surname from my_table;"
result <- setDT(sqlQuery(conn, sqlStr, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

x <- result[id == 12]
x
#    id  first_name      surname
# 1: 12     Roberto  Batti\xcc_n
Encoding(x$surname)
# "unknown"
Encoding(x[["surname"]] <- "latin1"
x
#    id  first_name  surname
# 1: 12     Roberto BattiÌ_n
```

The expected result is:

```
#    id  first_name  surname
# 1: 12     Roberto BATTIÓN
```

2nd try: trying to change the DBMS encoding in the connection

```
conn <- odbcConnect("my_db", DBMSencoding = "latin1")
sqlStr <- "SELECT id, first_name, surname from my_table;"
result <- setDT(sqlQuery(conn, sqlStr, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

x <- result[id == 12]
x
#    id  first_name      surname
# 1: 12     Roberto     BattiÌ_n

Encoding(x[["surname"]] <- "latin1"
x
#    id  first_name        surname
# 1: 12     Roberto BattiÃ\u008c_n
```

It gets worse. Any hint much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I use a an oracle-specific analog, but my first suggestion would be to nail down what encoding the DB uses? Alternatively, what about not specifying any encoding and going with R's default (not utf-8)

Comment: as the image says in my post the encoding looks like utf-8 but apparently it does not handle these characters. I changed the encoding of the table to latin1 but it does not fix it. in the database the name appears as BattiÌ_n

Comment: Actually I think i know what happened, the correct result comes from another data.base where the table has encoding latin1 so I guess the character is lost forever as it should have been written to a latin1 database?

Comment: good find. that seems plausible, not that I have any dba expertise. but then where did you get the expected output from?

Comment: from a mysqlserver database which is encoded in latin1...